SIGN UP in checkout page giving error in frontend in pwa venia setup
When i tried to enter first name, last name , email and tried to register in the checkout page , when i click on "SIGN UP " button, it not moving forward , after some time it will register in backend . but in frontend, it give error as below.
We have PWA Venia setup and here is checkoutPage.js file :
https://pastebin.com/ayfwffkt
frontend error :

Update :
when we replaced the old file code as below , it started to working
https://pastebin.com/8C2jEWuG
This below code is responsible for error, but i need this code to get the price in checkout page :
import { usePriceSummary } from '@magento/peregrine/lib/talons/CartPage/PriceSummary/usePriceSummary';

